# Are GUIDs Required for Replication with Amazon RDS Aurora?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, database-replication, amazon-aurora

Are GUIDs required for replication with Amazon Aurora? Or, can auto incrementing identity fields be used?  Is one preferred with Aurora?
Is the performance better with Aurora using GUIDs than standard MySQL using GUIDs?

Comment: Why would GUIDs be *required* for replication with Aurora?

Comment: AWS has globally distributed data centers. Aurora, running on AWS, can be replicated to up to 15 Availability Zones in those multiple globally distributed data centers. Seems reasonable that they might want a GUID for replication in such a dynamic environment to keep the masters and replica aligned properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GUIDs are not required with Amazon Aurora. Aurora's replication is physical, based on redo log replay, so doesn't need identifiers in the same manner as logical binlog replication (though binlogs are also supported). Anurag@AWS